# Bartering (Persuasion) - Discount and DC Amounts

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons

This week my players are heading into the major city and while they're there, will have a chance to buy some scrolls, potions, and two Uncommon magical items.  I've already come up with prices, but next up is the question of how to deal with them bartering with the owners.

They haven't bought anything from this city before, so I would assume that all the vendors are neutral (save for one who dislikes everyone) so they'd be at a clean slate.  I'd allow movement a bit if they engage in RP to talk to the vendor, learn about them, commiserate with them possibly; that however isn't important now.  My question is, how do you handle Relationships with Vendors and DC values for Persuasion?  This is what I've got personally:

Relationship      Persuasion DC

Unfriendly             25

Disliked               22

Neutral                19

Familiar               17

Friendly               15

Against those rolls:

Persuasion Over DC    Discount (%)

```
  1-6                -10

  7-11               -25

  12-19              -50

  20+                -75
```

Comment: To anyone answer: please remember to [support your subjective answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9228/how-do-we-appropriately-back-up-a-subjective-answer). **Answers that are unsupported idea generation should not be upvoted**. We're looking for supported answers to help OP.

Comment: Have you confirmed that both you and your players want to spend time doing this?

Comment: "How do you handle this?" isn't really a question we can answer because there's no "right" answer. Are you trying to decide if your version as suggested at the bottom of your answer is balanced? Because this site does not work well with idea-generation questions at all.

Comment: So, you've tagged this question with [dnd-5e] _and_ [dungeons-and-dragons]. The latter is usually only used for the series as a whole. Given that you've included [dnd-5e], I'm assuming that you are primarily interested in 5e, not necessarily previous editions. It might make sense to pick one tag or the other (of those two, I mean - you can add other non-game tags), likely just the [dnd-5e] tag.

Comment: @Theik "how do you handle this" isn't idea generation. It's asking for users who have utilized systems like this. I think we can answer that (as long as we support it), but we can also review their system.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking, if you want a homebrew-review please consult [How to ask a good homebrew questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8122/44723)